# Create materialized view from multiple tables with identical schemas

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, materialized-views

I am trying create a materialized view in Redshift.
I have 100 tables of the form

```
   user_1
   user_2
   ...
   user_100
```

Each table has the same schema. For example:

```
user_1

| id | user_id | date     | expense |
|----|---------|----------|---------|
| 1  | 1       | 20200521 | 200     |
| 2  | 2       | 20200601 | 100     |
| 3  | 1       | 20200603 | 90      |

user_2

| id | user_id | date     | expense |
|----|---------|----------|---------|
| 1  | 1       | 20200521 | 250     |
| 2  | 3       | 20200204 | 10      |
| 3  | 2       | 20200403 | 50      |
```

What I want to do is to create a materialized view which has all the rows from all 100 tables.
The objective is to run a queries to calculate the sum(expense) for given user_id between certain dates.

So my materialized view will be something like this:
    user_1

```
| id | user_id | date     | expense |
|----|---------|----------|---------|
| 1  | 1       | 20200521 | 200     |
| 2  | 2       | 20200601 | 100     |
| 3  | 1       | 20200603 | 90      |
| 4  | 1       | 20200521 | 250     |
| 5  | 3       | 20200204 | 10      |
| 6  | 2       | 20200403 | 50      |
```

I am having trouble with the CREATE query for this view.
Any guidance on the query to create this view is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about `UNION`ing the tables?

Keep in mind the difference between `UNION` (does implicit distinct) and `UNION ALL` which just combines rows from two tables as they come.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW users
AS 
SELECT * FROM user_1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM user_2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM user_3 UNION ALL
...
SELECT * FROM user_100
```